# Python, substitute all occurrences

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I have a python script and I am using re.sub to substitute variable.
If variable occurres only once everything is good but it gives me error when it occurres two or more times.
Any idea ? I am new to reg expressions. :/

My code:

```
    plot = re.sub(r'_choice1_','%s',plot)%data1
    plot = re.sub(r'_choice2_','%s',plot)%data2
```

Comment: And what error it is giving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use a regular expression here, there's absolutely no need when Python has a perfectly functional `str.replace`. Use regular expressions when you need to work with pattern matching - not for straight string replacements.

```
plot = plot.replace('_choice1_', data1)
plot = plot.replace('_choice2_', data2)
```

Anyway, the error is here:

```
plot = re.sub(r'_choice1_','%s',plot)%data1
                                     ^^^^^^
```

You're replacing `_choice1_` with `%s` then because your string formatting is at the *end* of the substitution, if you've replaced more than one, then applying string formatting will fail as you've only passed a single `data1` value... eg: if there's two `%s`'s in the resultant string, the `%` will fail as it doesn't have enough parameters to fill the rest of the formatting string with.

If you really, really, really wanted to use `re.sub`, then use:

```
plot = re.sub(r'_choice1_', data1 ,plot)
```

If you really, really, really wanted to use a regex in a meaningful way, then use a callable as a replacement, eg:

```
import re

data = ['egg', 'spam']
text = 'I would like some _choice1_ with my _choice2_ please'
new_text = re.sub('_choice(\d+)_', lambda m: data[int(m.group(1)) - 1], text)
# I would like some egg with my spam please
```

So in your case - that'd be `data = (data1, data2)`, and the regex engine will extract the digit off the end of choice, convert it to an int, then index into your array to return the string to sub. So if you had more than a couple or more advanced uses, then it's better than running a lot of multiple replaces as the regex engine can do it in one. However, for two values, I'd stick with `str.replace`.

Comment: Thanks that help me a lot. I am new to python but I need it as a part of by bachelor thesis (but not main part, only one script).
I don't know that there is a simplies way .
So again, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Jon said, you should use the string replacement. Otherwise, you're using regular expression substitution as if it were some sort of traditional string formatting. You need to do the following instead:

```
plot = re.sub(r'_choice1_', data1, plot)
plot = re.sub(r'_choice2_', data2, plot)
```

If you want to use string formatting which would  be completely redundant, you'd need to format directly after the format specifier with a tuple like so:

```
plot = re.sub(r'_choice1_', '%s' % (data1,), plot)
plot = re.sub(r'_choice2_', '%s' % (data2,), plot)
```